# How to apply first element of list to rest of list?

Tags: racket

Why is:

```
(apply (car (list 'xor)) '(#t #t))
```

application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 'xor

```
(apply (car (list (list 'xor))) '(#t #t))
```

application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(xor)

```
(apply (car '(xor #t #t)) (cdr '(xor #t #t)))
```

application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 'xor

How to apply first element of list to rest of list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, `'xor` is a symbol, not a procedure. In the program below, `xor` refers to the actual procedure, and is not a symbol -

```
(apply (car (list xor)) (list #t #t))
; #f

(apply (car (list xor)) (list #t #f))
; #t
```

Or simply -

```
(apply xor (list #t #f))
; #t
```

When you write `'(xor #t #t)`, `xor` is quoted and turned into symbol -

```
(car '(xor #t #t))
; 'xor
```

You can use quasi-quoting `` `(...) `` but you most unquote `,...` anything you don't want converted to a symbol -

```
(apply (car `(,xor #t #t)) (cdr `(,xor #t #t)))
; #f

(apply (car `(,xor #t #f)) (cdr `(,xor #t #f)))
; #t
```

Presumably the s-expressions will be constructed elsewhere -

```
(define sexpr1 (list xor #t #t))
(define sexpr2 (list xor #t #f))

(apply (car sexpr1) (cdr sexpr1)) ;#f
(apply (car sexpr2) (cdr sexpr2)) ;#t
```

---

If the s-expressions contain purely quoted datum, you can [eval](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html) the expression using a [namespace](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html).

We add `racket/base` to allow for procedure application. The procedure in your program, `xor`, is included with `racket/bool` -

```
(define (run-sexpr sexpr)
  (parameterize ((current-namespace (make-base-empty-namespace)))
    (namespace-require 'racket/base)
    (namespace-require 'racket/bool)
    (eval sexpr)))

(run-sexpr '(xor #t #t)) ;#f
(run-sexpr '(xor #t #f)) ;#t
```

Above we `eval` the entire s-expression, but this may not be desired. To make the program work, we only need `eval` to turn the `'xor` symbol into a meaningful procedure, `xor`. This is maybe closest to your original goal -

```
(define (run-sexpr sexpr)
  (parameterize (...)
    (...)
    (apply (eval (car sexpr)) ;only eval car
           (cdr sexpr))))     ;apply cdr verbatim

(run-sexpr '(xor #t #t)) ;#f
(run-sexpr '(xor #t #f)) ;#t
```

Comment: what if i want to apply the car to the cdr of and arbitrary s-expr? how to place the comma in front of car in a quasiquoted expression?

Comment: @X10D, the [eval](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html) guide linked in my edit shows you the things we have to think about when evaluating arbitrary quoted data. Please see my updated answer to see `'xor` symbol applied to various arguments.