# How to apply the first element of an arbitrary s-expression to the rest of it?

Tags: scheme, racket

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61626321/5920214) on a concrete example the following solution was suggested:

```
(apply (car `(,xor #t #f)) (cdr `(,xor #t #f)))
; #t
```

What would a function look like that applied the first element of list to the rest of it? How to place the comma in front of car of an arbitrary quasi-quoted expression to apply the first element of list to the rest of it?

Comment: This question is too confused to answer, I think.  You can apply functions to arguments: if the first element of your list is a function you can apply it to arguments.  If it's not, you can't.

Comment: That is just a specific example of `(apply (car ls) (cdr ls))`. (And you could also write `(list xor #t #f)`.)

Comment: Use `eval`? The question is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, do you have a procedure identifier?

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

(define exp (list 'xor #t #f))
(eval exp ns)
```

Or do you have the actual procedure?

```
(define exp (list xor #t #f))
(apply (car exp) (cdr exp))
```

And what's the need for using quasi quoting in the question, when you can get the desired effect without it?